# cannot clear a contact's field using javascript

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following code to try to clear the MaidenName fields in google apps contactsapp:

```
contact[i].setMaidenName(new String());
```

However, I get the following error:

> Service error: ContactsApp: [Line 1, Column 1479, element gContact:maidenName] Missing required text

Any ideas how to clear fields in google apps script contactsapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to clear a contact field.  If you can't set the content to an empty string.  You could try entering one space.

The string parameter for the `setMaidenName()` method is probably expecting a string literal, and not an object.  You are trying to create a string object.

I'd just use a string with an empty space and see what happens.

```
contact[i].setMaidenName(" ");
```

Comment: Still get an error: Service error: ContactsApp: [Line 1, Column 1615, element gContact:maidenname] Missing required text

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation to clear a contact field.  Maybe try entering an empty space `" "`  Or some text, like "Not Set".  And then check for "Not Set" if you need to.

Comment: yea i ended up setting a space but it is not really what i wanted.